# AsyncTask em loop infinito ao usar WallpaperMananger

Tags: java, android

Meu app estranhamente roda em loop infinito descontroladamente. Se trata de um simples código pra baixar uma imagem e aplicar como papel de parede.

Mas ao remover essa linha de código, o loop some, ou seja a asynctask volta a funcionar como esperado:

```
    WallpaperManager.getInstance(weakContext.get()).setBitmap(bitmap);
```

Já pensei que o problema poderia ser `WeakReference`, mas mesmo rodando o código dentro do método `onPostExecute()` usando um `Listener` para executar as mudanças dentro do Fragmento o problema persiste.

---

```
public class WorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private static final String TAG = "WorkerTask";
    private WeakReference<Context> weakContext;
    private WeakReference<ImageView> weakImage;
    private Bitmap wallpaper;
    private WallpaperListener wallpaperListener;

    WorkerTask(Context context, ImageView imageView, WallpaperListener listener){
        weakContext = new WeakReference<>(context);
        weakImage = new WeakReference<>(imageView);
        wallpaperListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: ");

        if (url[0].isEmpty()){
            throw new NullPointerException("URL Bad formatted");
        }

        /* Network */
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url[0])
                .build();
        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            /* Generate Image */
            wallpaper = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                    Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).byteStream());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (response != null) {
                response.close();
            }
        }

        return wallpaper;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);

        try {
            WallpaperManager.getInstance(weakContext.get()).setBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Logcat:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pq você não utiliza um lib como o `Picasso` ou `Glide` para fazer o download da imagem ?

Comment: qual a diferença? o problema não está no download em si, mas sim ao aplicar o papel de parede no dispositivo. Se voce remover do código (ou comentar) a linha que aplica o papel de parede a `Thread` não entra em loop.

Answer (score 0):

Eu descobri o que está causando esse bug, mas não o motivo principal. O android 8.1 tem uma função de combinar as cores do sistema com a hora do dia ou baseado na coloração do papel de parede. Ao configurar para combinar com o papel de parede, o bug aparece.

Eu estou testando em um dispositivo usando uma Rom customizada (RRemix 6.1.0), porém não sei dizer se o mesmo se aplica a dispositivos usando uma versão Stock.

---

#### Função com Bug

[image]
.

---

#### Gif de demostração

[image]